# Sql Getdate on previous years stats

Tags: sql, getdate

Im looking to report on Month to date(MTD) and previous years MTD
My code for MTD is 
`WHERE (Month(DateCompleted) = Month(getdate()) 
AND YEAR (DateCompleted) = YEAR (getdate ()))`
Is there a way i can look at last years exact month as this month

for for instance this query above gives me all sales for the month of june 2014 so far.
I want to compare them in a dynamic report so i would like to view June 2013 .
Cheers

Comment: Do i have to add a Date DateAdd()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subtract 1:

```
where Month(DateCompleted) = Month(getdate())
and Year(DateCompleted) = Year(getdate()) - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

It strikes me that simply decrementing the year would do this.

```
YEAR (DateCompleted) = YEAR (getdate ())-1
```